# How do you serialize from a json object to a list or a json list to a list of objects?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json data structure that could be either (ignoring all other json):

```
"warnings": [
    {
        ... some json ...
    },
    {
        ... some json ...
    }
]
```

Or it could also be

```
"warnings": {
    ... some json ...
}
```

The following code in jackson works for the first case:

```
@JsonProperty("warnings")
private List<Warning> warnings;
```

But it won't work for the second. What is the correct practise for mapping using the jackson library (+ annotations if possible) such that it will map json either in the form of a list of json or an object of json but both to the same field. This appears to be a fairly common problem when receiving data from external systems though Jackson doesn't handle it out of the box (in my eyes it should because there is very little difference between a list and a single object in real terms).

Comment: I'd say the correct practice would be: If it's ever a list, make sure it's *always* a list (even if the list has only one entry).

Comment: _there is very little difference between a list and a single object in real terms_ This would be best modeled as a list with one item in JSON. It's very unfortunate that your provider produces such JSON. There is no built in functionality to do this in Jackson.

Comment: Thanks for the response @T.J.Crowder but unfortunately it's not an option for me to change that. I could inform the other team that their data structure is incorrect (and needs changing) but realistically they won't change that any time soon.

Comment: Parse it with a non-Jacksonesque parser into Maps and Lists, then query the structure to see what object type "warnings" is.

Comment: @Dropkick: Ugh, that's no fun. I would raise it with them anyway, in hopes they at least don't make this mistake again... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue actually more simply than all these solutions put together. Although it was slightly more painful than I anticipated (due to jackson classpath resolution issues).

I upgraded my library version for jackson from 1.9.2 to 2.4.1 and changed the type for `Warning warning` to `List<Warning>`. It appears that jackson 2.4.1 automatically casts a single object to a list type when performing deserialization - handy!

My classpath issues highlighted though how fragile monolithic applications are that rely on the same libraries at their core and that it may be better to split up a monolithic app into multiple smaller applications to aid with upgrading libraries.

Comment: Can you show a full example? I was not able to reproduce this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it doesn't matter about the full example as an object and list should suffice in the json example above. You will though need to use the 1.9.2 Jackson library version.

I upgraded to use com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1 version as opposed to the older library. In retrospect I'm unsure why this solution was downvoted because upgrading to a new library version that supports automatically mapping objects or list json to a List.class is not an invalid answer.

Comment: I'd like you to prove _It appears that jackson 2.4.1 automatically casts a single object to a list type when performing deserialization_ with a reproducible example, because it doesn't do that for me.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson relies on the types of the properties or fields to determine how to deserialize some JSON. There is no type that can act as both a `List<Warning>` and an `Warning`. (Well, there's `Object` but that doesn't hint to Jackson how to deserialize to specific target types.)

One option is to set the field as type `Object` and let Jackson produce a `LinkedHashMap` in one case (single object) or a `List` of `LinkedHashMap` (array of objects). Alternatively, you can provide your own deserializer for that field and produce a `Warning` object or a `List<Warning>` depending on the JSON you find.

Another way to do this is to work with `ObjectNode` rather than a POJO. You can then check the type of the `JsonNode` you get back with `get(String)`, while traversing.

In either case, you'll have to constantly check if `instanceof List` or check `JsonNode#isArray()`.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds reasonable I'll give it a try. I'd rather not try the second option as performing processing on ObjectNode's is painful (we do this a lot and I'd like to avoid it in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with gson by providing a deserializer for the type containing the warning property to the gson context. 
Assuming class TypeOfRootElement as container class and class WarningType used for warnings, do something like this in the deserializer:

```
public TypeOfRootElement deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT,
                    final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
  TypeOfRootElement result=new ...;
  JsonObject jsonRoot=json.getAsJsonObject();
  final JsonElement jsonWarningsElement = root.get("warnings");
  List<WarningType> warnings=null;
  if (jsonWarningsElement.isJsonArray())
  {
     warnings=context.deserialize(jsonWarningsElement, WarningType.class);
  }
  else
  {
    warnings=Collections.singletonList(context.deserialize(jsonWarningsElement,
                                       WarningsType.class));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask for it in gson - would require another library/dependency or re-writing all other code to accommodate the new library so I can't really use this suggestion - thanks for taking the time though.